# Where are optional packages definition of debian installer stored?

Tags: debian, system-installation, dpkg

I am creating a custom debian ISO image. When you install debian there is a choice what packages you pack to install, like on this picture:

[image]

But I cant find where packages list of this options are stored. For example, there is the option "Web server", but it installs not just Apache2 but other packages as well.

All data are in tasksell package:

```
tasksel-data_xxxxxxxxxxxxx.deb
```

in `/usr/share/tasksell/debian-tasks.desc`. It seems I need to repack this dpkg somehow to change this menu and packages.

But I need to sign .deb after that and add keys...

So my question is - where are the package list definitions stored and how can I add my own options to this list?

Answer (score 1):

These are tasks, defined in [`tasksel`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/tasksel). Each one now corresponds to a package, *e.g.* [`task-web-server`](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/task-web-server).

To add your own, you can define other [task files](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/tasksel/-/tree/master/tasks) (see [the task `README`](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/tasksel/-/blob/master/tasks/README)).